# Installing from github instead of apt

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-installation, aptitude

Im using Ubuntu 20.10

**Backstory**

I've been trying to install omnet++
but I've got an error while running some samples with satellites. It gave the error "[osgEarth]* [Horizon] No horizon info installed in callback" and appearently it means that I should update the osgearth package.

Problem is, when I install it using aptitude, all I get is

> osgearth is already the newest version (2.9.0+dfsg-1).

but in github ( https://github.com/gwaldron/osgearth ) there is v 3.1

btw, there is no installation guide for linux

**problem**

how do I install from github repo on top of the apt package...

`dpkg -L osgearth`
yields

> /. /usr /usr/bin /usr/bin/osgearth_atlas /usr/bin/osgearth_boundarygen
> /usr/bin/osgearth_cache /usr/bin/osgearth_conv
> /usr/bin/osgearth_overlayviewer /usr/bin/osgearth_package
> /usr/bin/osgearth_tfs /usr/bin/osgearth_tileindex
> /usr/bin/osgearth_version /usr/bin/osgearth_viewer /usr/share
> /usr/share/doc /usr/share/doc/osgearth
> /usr/share/doc/osgearth/README.Debian
> /usr/share/doc/osgearth/README.md /usr/share/doc/osgearth/copyright
> /usr/share/man /usr/share/man/man1
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_atlas.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_backfill.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_boundarygen.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_cache.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_conv.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_demo.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_overlayviewer.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_package.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_terraineffects.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_tfs.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_tileindex.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_version.1.gz
> /usr/share/man/man1/osgearth_viewer.1.gz /usr/share/osgearth
> /usr/share/osgearth/fonts /usr/share/doc/osgearth/changelog.Debian.gz
> /usr/share/osgearth/fonts/arial.ttf
> /usr/share/osgearth/fonts/times.ttf

and the file structure of the unzipped github repo is:

> CMakeLists.txt  data        docs         README.md  tests CMakeModules
> Dockerfile  LICENSE.txt  src

So.. they don't even look similar

Sorry for asking something this fundamental.

Comment: "You can install the osgEarth SDK and toolset using `vcpkg`. First, download and bootstrap [`vcpkg`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) following the instructions on the web site." And there are [instructions for Linux](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg#quick-start-unix).

Comment: It just doesn't work.. Error: Building package coin:x64-linux failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `./vcpkg update`, then
submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
  Package: coin:x64-linux
  Vcpkg version: 2021-01-13-unknownhash